# find max occurence in multiple lists

Tags: python

so i have 2 lists that contain which day of the year individuals visited London and Sydney

```
names=['james','lin','mark','james','line','mark'.'lin','mark','james','mark']
dates[london]=['2-3-1999','3-3-1999','23-7-1999','25-12-1999','13-6-1999'.'1-1-1999'.'5-3-1999','10-4-1999','9-11-1999','23-4-1999']
dates[sydney]=['21-1-2011', '24-1-2011', '24-1-2011', '02-02-2011', '03-02-2011', '19-4-2011', '14-5-2011', '06-11-2011', '07-3-2011']


# the above dates are in the form  day:month:year
```

how would i be able to use the above lists to find which month  had the most vistors from these people  #answer is the third month.

i believe i that i have to use some sort of indexing, but i am not sure it can be done

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  This sounds like a homework problem...  What have you tried?

Comment: print(dates.index(max(dates))) i have tried that but doesnt yeild the right answer

Comment: also it would be helpful if you will provide expected output in your question

Comment: the expected output should be 3

Comment: Is `dates` a dictionary?  What you have written isn't valid syntax.  If it is a dictionary, it should be `dates['london']` and `dates['sydney']`.

Answer (score 1):

```
l = [map(lambda x: x.split("-")[1], dates1 + dates2).count(str(mon)) for mon in range(1, 13)]
result = l.index(max(l)) + 1
```

where

`dates1 + dates2` - is a list consisting of two input lists (I'm not sure this is what you wanted, though..)

`lambda x: x.split("-")[1]` - means we create a function, which takes string, split it by "-" and returns second part (month)

`map(f(), coll)` - means we apply function `f` to each member of `coll` collection and get collection of results

`range(1, 13)` gives us [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12] - numbers of months

`[f(x) for x in collection]` is list comprehension (which is smth similar to map()) - convenient feature to generate lists - on this step we have frequencies of every month in one list

`l.index(max(l)) + 1` - now all we need is to find max element and return its index.

Comment: Call me crazy... but somehow I don't think the OP is going to understand that.

Comment: Sorry, I could not fit it in one line :) However, it can be a good demonstration of Python's functional features.. especially if OP is interested in language.

Comment: No doubt. I am just saying that maybe an explanation is warranted here, because the OP is already struggling with very basic concepts.

Comment: added some explanations

Answer (score 0):

One easy solution if save in a list contained the 12 months the amount that have in the list you provided, for example :

```
# create a list with 12 positions initialized with zero, (months)
months = [0]*12

def count_months(dates):
  # list contains the specified dates      
  for item in dates:
    # first we split by the '-' character and then get the second : is the month
    _month = int(item.split('-')[1])
    month[_month] += 1    

london = ['2-3-1999','3-3-1999','23-7-1999','25-12-1999','13-6-1999'.'1-1-1999'.'5-3-1999','10-4-1999','9-11-1999','23-4-1999']
count_months(london)

#to find the most occur we only need to find the max of the list
max = -1
for i in range(0,13):
  if month[i] > max:
    max = a[i]
    maxIndex = i

print maxIndex
```

To various list you only has to pass the list to a method like teh code explained before and then fin the max element.

Comment: What exactly is `dates(london)` ?

Comment: It's only a sample based in the list that the user provided before, it  has to be iterable to this work. You could think in this of a List based in the question

Comment: No it isn't. That is not valid python syntax.

Comment: @rantanplan `function(argument)` is valid syntax.

Comment: @sdasdadas didn't see any function. At the time I asked, it was treated as some kind of variable. Now it is correct.

Comment: @sdasdadas but `function(argument) = assignment`, as contained in OPs question, isn't...

Comment: @l4mpi Oh I have no idea what the OP is going for. I ain't touching that.

Answer (score 0):

Just go through your list and find max value of repeating
use `string` instead the `int` in list `a`, for example:

```
import random
a = [ random.randrange(10) for i in range(30)]
max = 0
value = ''
for i in set(a):
    if max < a.count(i):
      max = a.count(i)
      value = i
print("value: {0}\ntimes: {1}".format(value, max))
```